# Is there a way to change the speed of a media element

Tags: silverlight, media-player

In silverlight, is there a way to change the playback speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of Silverlight 4 there is no way to change the playback speed of the `MediaElement`. In WPF there is a SpeedRatio property which has not been made available in Silverlight.

There is currently a feature request for it on [UserVoice](http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/310709-media-playback-variable-speed-rate?ref=title).

Answer (score 1):

A `PlayBackRate` property was introduced on Silverlight 5

[MediaElement.PlaybackRate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.playbackrate%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)